# WLS, backup process and Windows Update - disk space lost

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was running `Restic` within WLS when my PC restarted due to an update. The backup process was writing to my external HDD on `/mnt/j`.

After the update, the computer restarted and I noticed that I was low on space on drive `C:`.

I ran WinDirStat and it showed me this:

[image]

If I attempt to list that folder now in WLS, here is what I get:

```
me@server:~$ cd /mnt/j/
me@server:/mnt/j$ ls -l
ls: cannot open directory .: Invalid argument
```

Note, somewhere in the middle, I reformatted `J:` (ie. `/mnt/j`) thinking that it was lost as there was nothing showing in Windows Explorer (even though space was taken up)

How do I get this space back?

Comment: Reset the legacy WSL using my answer in my profile then update to 1709 and install the new WSL (if you use it you will appreciate the improvements)

Comment: Does updating to 1709 prevent future resets of being needed or are resets part of life with WLS?

Comment: Legacy WSL will receive no updates to Ubuntu.  The non-beta Windows Store WSL Ubuntu will be updated and unless major changes happen again will not require the environment to be reset

Comment: Unmount J drive from WSL.

Comment: @Biswa I ended up using the Windows binary after installing the new WLS...

Comment: @Biswa I uninstalled the old WLS and reinstalled the one from the store. Instead of installing Restic under WLS, I used the 64-bit Windows binary.